# spring security using a custom permissionEvaluator for use in authorize tag with accesscontrollist

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am having issues while trying to inject custom permission evaluator in spring security:

My front-end code looks like this:

```
<sec:accesscontrollist hasPermission="VIEW_HEADER,VIEW_ANYTHING" domainObject="${userWebsiteLocationContext}" >
    <b>This is a TEST</b>
</sec:accesscontrollist>
```

and I am trying the following within my spring security config :
    
        ...

```
...
<security:global-method-security>
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="org.atd.storefront.security.impl.DefaultPermissionsEvaluator" >
</bean>

<bean id="defaultExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" >
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" ></property>
</bean>
```

my custom permission evaulator simply returns false but the text is always displayed. I've also tried the solution at https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1749 and tried to use the custom defined decision manager bean: access-decision-manager-ref="webAccessDecisionManager" with no avail.

I don't get any exceptions, the hasPermission of my custom permissionevaluator just isn't called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to register an implementation of `PermissionEvaluator` for the `accesscontrollist` tag to pick it up and use it.

My advice would be to set a breakpoint in the `doStartTag()` method of the `org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AccessControlListTag` method and inspect which `PermissionEvaluator` it's really using.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for 'twas what brought be to the actual issue... spring gave access because my domainObject was null
        if (domainObject == null) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("domainObject resolved to null, so including tag body");
            }

            // Of course they have access to a null object!
            return evalBody();
        }